# Can date format current time for GMT timezone?

Tags: date, timezone

When I run `date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"` I receive `20171225203309` here in CET time zone.

Can I use `date` to obtain a the current time in the same format, but for timezone GMT?

Comment: If you're in CET (CEST) do you really want GMT/UTC or do you want the UK/Portugal WET (WEST) timezone? UTC/GMT never changes but WET (WEST) jumps twice a year like your own timezone.

Comment: @roaima The first (GMT/UTC).

Comment: @muru But `date -u` only mentioned (as answer) here.

Comment: @Drux special case only for UTC. The general way for using another timezone is the `TZ` environment variable. OP of that question even mentions this: "Looking through man date I see that I can have the time output as UTC"

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use `date -u` (*universal time*) which is equivalent to GMT.

Quoting `date` manual:

> ‘-u’ ‘--utc’ ‘--universal’
>
> Use Universal Time by operating as if the ‘TZ’ environment variable
>        were set to the string ‘UTC0’.  UTC stands for Coordinated
>        Universal Time, established in 1960.  Universal Time is often
>        called “Greenwich Mean Time” (GMT) for historical reasons.
>        Typically, systems ignore leap seconds and thus implement an
>        approximation to UTC rather than true UTC.

Answer (score 21):

Use the following command:

```
TZ=GMT date
```

The same format:

```
TZ=GMT date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
20171225194014
```